# "NSUnknownKeyException" message with non-existent item

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I got this message when running the app:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<examSelf 0x6854ea0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key examQBodyTextView.'
```

The funny thing is I removed all of the related things with "examQBodyTextView" from the code since they are not needed anymore.

Note: I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the XIBs in the Storyboard or elsewhere has a hanging reference to `examQBodyTextView`.

Its blowing up when the View instantiates.

Go through your XIB's and look for an object, mostly likely a Files Owner which has a yellow triangle next to its connection when you right click it. Disconnect that and you should be OK.